# Is it possible to run query while debugging procedure in aqua data studio?

Tags: sybase, aqua-data-studio, aqua

I found a documentation of SQL Debugger for Sybase ASE
[documentation of SQL Debugger for Sybase ASE](https://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio/sybase_sql_debugger)

But I want to run queries while I am stopping in breakpoint,
using temp tables from the procedure, and vaiables from the procedure

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for the same features. Did you checked out aqua-data-studio?